# Is there a way to schedule a Data Factory trigger that runs multiple times everyday BUT ONLY DURING A SPECIFIC TIME FRAME?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I've created a pipeline with a web activity that uses REST API calls to my Synapse instance and pauses it at the end of every day. I'm trying to schedule it in Data Factory but the problem is I can't schedule it in the way I need. I want the pipeline to be triggered every hour but only between 6 PM and 10 PM everyday.

But ADF doesn't seem to provide this facility where a pipeline could be run only between a fixed timeframe  every single day. I don't want my Synapse instance to be paused every hour during the day time.

Is there a way to bypass this limitation of Azure Data Factory scheduling?

Comment: Hi LearneR, If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept(mark) it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Hello LearneR, did you get the answer you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can using Azure logic app [Recurrence trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-actions-triggers#recurrence-trigger) to achieve that:
[image]

Create a Recurrence trigger to call the data factory pipeline run with [Get a pipeline run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azuredatafactory/#get-a-pipeline-run) action.

Trigger the pipeline runs in [18,19,20,21,22](6 PM~10 PM) clock every day.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. I let the trigger run hourly and added an If-statement to a new pipeline that checks if the time is within the right timeframe, if so, trigger the original pipeline, else, do nothing.

Comment: You are a genious.

Answer (score 2):

We can have trigger at any time by specifying in Hours tab while creating a trigger:

[image: Attached Sample Image]

Comment: Question. In this setup does this mean it will run everyday at 8, 11, 15, 19, 23? How about if we make recurrence value as "3" in "Day(s)"? Meaning it will run 3 times a day?

Comment: @ZeroCool -- that would mean every 3 days it will run at the specified times.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use Logic App or anything else if you want to be good with Data Factory. Can use does not mean should use. just put 18 into Hours box then click anywhere blank outside the box, repeat this with 19 and any other hours will give your Schedule execution times 08:00,19:00,20:00 ...